# Dynamically update CDATA when find "&commat;" string on perticular node in xml file

Tags: c#, xml

Can you please tell me how to dynamically update CDATA in xml file before load xml file

```
 Input:
    <ref ref-type="sectiona">sdsadsd <email>EffectiveHealthCare@ahrq.hhs.gov</email>sdasd  &commat; Sec asdd</ref>
    <ref ref-type="sec">test Sec</ref>
    <ref ref-type="sec">seesdasdasd <email>EffectiveHealthCare &commat; dasdasdasd</email>asdad Sec</ref>
    <ref ref-type="sec"> Sec</ref>

Output:
<ref ref-type="sectiona"sdsadsd <email>><![CDATA[EffectiveHealthCare@ahrq.hhs.gov]]</email>sdasd  &commat; Sec asdd></ref>
<ref ref-type="sec">test Sec</ref>
<ref ref-type="sec"> Sec</ref>
<ref ref-type="sec">seesdasdasd <email><![CDATA[EffectiveHealthCare &commat; dasdasdasd]]</email>asdad Sec></ref>
```

Comment: Is your input well-formed XML? That is, has the `&commat;` entity been declared? This is crucial to know, because processing ill-formed XML requires completely different tools and techniques from processing well-formed XML.

Comment: any one please tell me how to fixed it

Comment: If you want help, then start by answering the question.

Comment: means what ...how to start answering

Comment: Is your input document accepted as well-formed XML by an XML parser? This will only be the case if it refers to a DTD that defines the `&commat;` external entity.